# Persistently setting the default name on an Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, manifest

I have an Android project. The name is correctly set in the Android manifest (android:label), the package name is also set correctly (package="com.etc..."). Now, when I add this project to Eclipse the name picked up by the package explorer is actually the name of my launch activity. As you may imagine this is not what I want.

I can rename the project by selecting it in the package explorer, pressing F2 and changing the name. However, once I remove this project from Eclipse and re-add it then the name that is picked up is again that of my first activity.

Does anybody know how to tell Eclipse to pick the manifest's application name and not the launch activity name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Android-specific import process currently has different behaviour to the non-specific Eclipse import process. As Rajesh points out, you can still use the latter via *File* -> *Import* -> *General* -> *Existing Projects into Workspace*, which does not exhibit this issue.

This is further explained in [this Google issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=40161&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars).

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses the *.project* file to store the project's metadata. Change the *.project* file in the project folder to reflect the name that you want in the `<name>` tag.

Comment: Oh, yes, I forgot to mention this in my original post. The <name> tag is also correctly set. However, the same problem remains.

Comment: How are you adding the project to Eclipse?

Comment: File -> New -> Android Project -> Create project from existing source

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating the project every time? You can create the project once, export it and use _File_ -> _Import_ -> _General_ -> _Existing Projects into Workspace_ every time you want to add it to the workspace. This way, whatever changes you did to the project will be preserved

Comment: Well, actually this is a project that will go to the public. That's the reason why I would like it to have a default proper name. 

I find it odd that Eclipse wouldnt use the Manifest name though.